# How do we change the default image preview in opencart?

Tags: opencart

I need a solution to change the default image preview in Opencart

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7ICF.png)

Answer (score 0):

The image preview is generated using a jQuery plugin called [magnific-popup](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/), so if you check in your `/catalog/view/theme/your-theme/template/product/product.tpl` file for `.magnificPopup` , unbind the element to the plugin to remove the image preview.